# proving that a point is a center of a circle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

If i want to prove that a point $O$ is a center of a circle.
is it sufficient to say that if $A,B,C$ are points On the circle and $AO=BO=CO$ so point $O$ is the center because of: Through any three points, Not all on the same line, there lies a unique circle.

Or the last sentence isn't sufficient to say that $O$ is the center and i need something else to connect between them and prove it?

Comment: The word 'efficient' in the question is confusing me. But your argument is right and it is generally used. If you are asking whether the last statement needs a proof, that depends on the theorems taught to you.

Comment: That sounds reasonable to me, but you're going to have to define "center" and tell us whether that last result is something that you're allowed to assume or not. (Why focus on an "efficient" proof? "Efficient" should be secondary to "correct and functional". Perhaps you mean something like "effective", though.)

Comment: i don't know it seems like i need to add something like say $O$ isn't the center and to show by contradiction

Comment: Aha, you mean "sufficient".

Comment: yes sorry. ill fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly the question, the answer is yes: a circle is uniquely determined by three non-collinear points $\,A,B,C\,$ and a fourth, different one $\;O\;$ which is at the same distance from each of the first three.

The proof is easy: form the triangle $\;\Delta ABC\;$, then the circle $\,O\;$ is this triangle's circumcircle...If you're not sure about this you can try drawing the perpendicular bisector of any two pairs of these three points, say of $\;AB\,,\,BC\;$ . As any point on the perp. bisector of $\;AB\;$ is at the same distance from $\,A\,$ and from $\,B\,$, and every point on the p.b. of $\,BC\;$ is at the same distance from $\,B\,$ and from $\,C\,$ , the intersection of these two p.b.'s (why do they **have** to intersect?!) is precisely $\,O\,$ ...